# Is "sure does" a colloquial phrase?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adverbs, grammaticality-in-context

In an essay I wrote this sentence :

> A car does not enable you to travel thousands of kilometres in a couple of hours, but an aircraft **sure does**.

My teacher said "sure does" should be "surely does". However, I have heard natives saying "sure does" many times. Is this some kind of colloquial phrase?

Comment: sure is :) (sorry)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Yes - ***[It] sure does*** is unquestionably a "colloquial" affirmative response.

---

***Sure*** (along with others such as ***hard, near, clean, right, close,...***) is what's called a...

> [**flat adverb**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb) (Wikipedia)
>    *an adverb that has the same form as a related adjective*

But *not all flat adverbs are "equal"*. Sometimes the "flat" form (as opposed to the ***-ly*** form ***hardly, nearly, cleanly,...***) has a slightly different meaning, or only one version is ever used in specific contexts. And in the case of ***sure = surely***, there's no doubt that many if not most "careful speakers" would consider the usage at least *slightly* "non-standard, dialectal, informal".

To illustrate that point (and assuming that the first pair of examples below are far more likely to occur in relatively formal contexts, whereas the second pair are more likely to be informal), consider these counts from Google Books...

> "FORMAL" - favours ***-ly*** form
>   [*Sinners will **surely** go to hell*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will%20surely%20go%20to%20hell%22) (1650 hits)
>    [*Sinners will **sure** go to hell*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will%20sure%20go%20to%20hell%22) (362 hits)
>
> "INFORMAL" - favours "flat" form
>   [*She **surely** gets on my nerves*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22surely%20gets%20on%20my%22) (5 hits)
>    [*She **sure** gets on my nerves*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sure%20gets%20on%20my%22) (51 hits)

---

In practice, to avoid ***surely*** sounding a little "stilted" in OP's exact context (which we know is relatively formal, because it features ***does not*** rather than contracted ***doesn't***), a better solution would be to simply switch to a difference but equivalent adverb...

> *A car does not [blah blah], but an aircraft **definitely** does*

---

I think it's also worth flagging up a minor aspect of usage that came to mind when considering what I'd written in my "TL;DR:" summary above. Note that the "formal, non-flat" versions would usually (almost *always*, for certain adverbs) position the ***-ly*** adverb ***after*** the verb it modifies...

> *This usage **is unquestionably** "colloquial"*
>    *This usage **is definitely** "colloquial"*

...but when I consider these possible alternatives (remarking on the weather, say)...

> 1: *It **is sure** hot!*
>   2: ***It's sure*** hot!
>    3: *It **sure is** hot!*
>    4: *It **is surely** hot!*
>    5: ***It's surely*** hot!
>    6: *It **surely is** hot!*

...it seems to me that although *in principle* all permutations are "valid", only #3 (and to a lesser extent, #4 and #6) are really "natural".

Comment: Bravo for the complete answer!